# Dump BIOS configuration

Tags: security, bios

I have an old HP Z2100 plotter whose firmware and data is located on a now 12 years old laptop PATA disk and which I'd like to replace with a CF card before the disk inevitably dies. The computer in it is a custom x86 (Celeron) based board, with the ATA password stored somewhere in the BIOS - either hardcoded or in NVRAM.

So I managed to get ssh root access (for those hitting Google: enter the service menu, go to "disable firewall" and then you can ssh in without a password) on the printer, so far so good - but how do I now dump the content of the BIOS itself (if I do have to resort to IDA, hope not) and the NVRAM? The `nvram` module is unfortunately not present.

The OS is "MontaVista(R) Linux(R) Professional Edition 4.0.1 (0502020)" and I seem to have the basic 'nix commandline tools.

Comment: I'd assume it would heavily depend on the BIOS how the BIOS decides to store the password (and it may also encrypt that password). Given it's 12 years old and PATA, the disk can't be that large, and if you have ssh access the harddisk should already be unlocked, so why don't save the complete contents of the harddisk e.g. via `scp`? That should be easier than trying to get at the BIOS password.

Comment: Because I suspect that the system will fail to boot from the CF card as the BIOS will try to unlock it, additionally I don't want to risk FS inconsistencies. Yeah I could in theory try to stop all services cleanly, remount-ro all partitions and then dd the image across the network but if there was a standardized way I'd prefer this one ;)

Comment: I suppose it should be possible to find out how the CF card reacts if it gets sent the unlock command without having a password set. My guess would be some kind of mild error, and I'd also guess that the BIOS would continue to boot in this case (what else should it do?). But if you find out a generic way to crack BIOS harddisk passwords, that of course would also be interesting.